# Log function name and object attributes with LoggerMixin

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, mixins

I want `LoggerMixin` to log

- the name of the function (`info`) which invoked its instance
- the attributes of the object (`self.brand` and `self.wheel`) belonging to that funcion.

How can I achieve this? See below where I'm currently at:

```
import logging


class LoggerMixin:
    def log(self):
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(funcName)s-%(message)s')
        return logging.info(f'func name is {self.__class__.__name__}')


class Car(LoggerMixin):
    def __init__(self, brand: str, wheel: int):
        self.brand = brand
        self.wheel = wheel

    def info(self):
        print(f'my brand is {self.brand} and i have {self.wheel} wheel')


obj1 = Car(brand='bmw', wheel=4)
obj1.info()
```

Answer (score 0):

- `basicConfig` could be defined outside the class.
- You should add an `__init__()` method to `LoggerMixin`.
- Initialize the inherited `LoggerMixin` object by calling `super().__init__()`.
- Invoke `logging.info()` locally on `self.logger` so it knows the `funcName` correctly.

My recommendation with further minor improvements:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(funcName)s – %(message)s')


class LoggerMixin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()


class Car(LoggerMixin):
    def __init__(self, brand: str, wheel: int):
        super().__init__()

        self.brand = brand
        self.wheel = wheel

    def info(self):
        self.logger.info(f'My brand is {self.brand} and I have {self.wheel} wheel(s)')


obj1 = Car(brand='bmw', wheel=4)
obj1.info()
```